# log4j: how to parameterize a log file in XML configuration

Tags: java, log4j

Is there a way to "parameterize" a Log4J XML configuration file (log4j.xml) so multiple running instances of a program will write their logs to separate files?

I have a setup where I can start multiple instances of a program (the same program is used for all instances), where each separate instance is provided with configuration information in order for it to do its job, including an identifier. The logging is being handled by log4j/slf4j.

Not surprisingly, I've found that the log output from any running instances is showing up in just one log file. I want to be able to set it up so that each instance has its own log file, named appropriately to associate with the instance.

Can this be done via the XML configuration, or would I need to do this from the Java API (within the program code)?

Answer (score 0):

you can create appenders dynamically in the code and can specify the appender to use for the logging. 
you can refer the 
https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j2/multiple-appenders/

The below URL is java doc for log4j for configuration showing addAppenders etc.
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/index.html

Comment: It looks like you are referencing Log4J 2. I am using just Log4J. I have not looked into Log4J 2, but am under the impression that it's different and may require a lot of rewrite/refactor.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/08/log4j-tutorial-how-to-send-log-messages-to-different-log-files/